# Element directive template changes not reflected in browser?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I've got an element directive defined:

```
mod.directive("saleList", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "templates/sale-list.html"
    };
});
```

and when I load the `/search` route I see it downloaded in the Network tab (I have cache in the browser disabled):

```
when('/search/:zip', {
    templateUrl: "templates/sale-list.html",
    controller: 'SearchController'
}).
```

However, I **do not see** one of its referenced element directives. Consider this snippet of HTML from the `sale-list.html`:

```
<sales-in ng-show="salesInZip()"></sales-in>
<sale-card ng-repeat="sale in sales.local"></sale-card>
```

I don't see the `sale-card` getting downloaded.

Now, the reason I'm going at it from this direction is because if I make a change in the `sale-card` I don't see them reflected in the browser until I reboot the machine. This probably has something to do with the fact that I use WebStorm as my IDE and it has its own local server that isn't easily configurable or clearble.

What's going on here?

**NOTE:** this just started happening recently, and I wonder if it's because something changed in the angular libraries; I am using their CDN to download the most recent version:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.1/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I do not have any solid arguments against it at the time, but I would prefer *not* to use the same template both as route and as directive. The route template could be as simple as: `<sale-list></sale-list>` for your case. Also, are you sure the JS files defining the `sales-in` and `sales-card` directives are getting loaded? Is the module containing them properly "required" by an active module?

Comment: Have you checked if `sales.local` returns an empty array?

Answer (score 0):

```
mod.directive("saleList", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: "templates/sale-list.html"
    };
});
```

Try this.